# Research Paper in LyX

Tags: lyx

I am a student writing a research paper using LyX for the first time. I found on YouTube [Conference paper in Lyx](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2l580M7r6u0&t=482s) about author guidelines. Is it fine to submit a research paper to professor (later to be sent to journal) using these CVPR guidelines? If not, what should I do? Also, professor wants the document class to be REVTeX 4 rather than standard `article` but LyX gives errors as shown in the following figure. How could I solve this error? Thanks in advance!!

[image]

Comment: from your print screen is quite difficult to say what it is wrong. First you need to specify your system (windows, linux, osx, etc) and which tex distribution you are using (miktex, livetex, etc). Since you want to use a "custom" class, the above information is crucial

Comment: when it comes to a non standard class, i find more convenient to use LaTeX instead of LyX (note that the output will be the same)

Comment: @Yorgos `revtex` isn't that "custom", after all it is on CTAN.

Comment: Raunak, isn't the error you get quite clear? You have written keywords after writing some normal text. You need to place it right up there with the title, author, etc.

Comment: yes but it doesn't list as an option from LyX menu (for that reason i used quotation marks..

Comment: @Yorgos I am using MikTex 2.9 on windows 8.1

Comment: @Yorgos Yes it is ...

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I have written title, author and abstract before keywords like in any paper.

Comment: Is there anything else before the keywords? Exactly how did you write title, author and abstract?

Comment: There is a box below File and Edit options. I checked Title to write title. I included everything (name, dept., institute, email) in the author section. To write in multiple lines, I used Ctrl+Enter. Similarily, I created Abstract just below which I wrote Keywords.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Sorry for my mistake and mis-information

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You are right. I included a box (Ctrl+L) just before keywords. Now it is showing no errors but abstract is now showing before the title and the author section is completely missing in the generated PDF.

Comment: I don't know what could be the cause, can you make a minimal example showing the problem? (See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4488 and for more on making MWEs.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I think it is because I am using CVPR author kit. Even an unedited version shows errors in outputting PDF file.

Comment: Ah, right, I was kind of focused on `revtex`, sorry. But anyway, you shouldn't be using both `revtex` and the `cvpr` stuff I think. Remove the `cvpr` package etc. and use the RevTeX documentclass. (Looks like CVPR is for a specific conference, so unless you are actually writing a proceedings paper for that conference, there's no immediate reason to use it.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I think you have an answer there

Comment: @DaiBowen I wrote up an answer.

Answer (score 2):

So there seems to be two different problems here.

1. All the elements belonging to the title material, i.e. authors, title, keywords etc., need to be before everything else in the LyX document. This is quite clear from the error, I think. You had something else in between title material.
2. You're mixing the CVPR stuff and RevTeX. As I remember/understand it CVPR is designed for proceedings papers to a specific conference. RevTeX on the other hand is a class for submissions to journals published by American Physical Society (the Physical Review series), and can also be used for journal belonging to the American Institute of Physics (I don't know which journals these are), and perhaps some other physics journals (cf. [Dai Bowen's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343647/research-paper-in-lyx/352079?noredirect=1#comment865206_352079)). So you need to figure out where you're submitting to (I cannot know), and act accordingly:

   - Are you submitting a proceedings paper to the conference for which CVPR was made? Then use the standard `article` class and ignore RevTeX.
   - Are you submitting to a journal that uses RevTeX? Use RevTeX, and ignore CVPR.
   - Are you submitting to some other journal that doesn't tell you to use RevTeX? Look in the author instructions on the journal website, and see if they

     1. Allow LaTeX submissions at all

     and if yes,

     2. see if they have a specific documentclass or similar that they require you to use. Then ignore both CVPR and RevTeX, and use this other class.

Comment: Thanks, technicality on the journal front - `revtex` is made by the American Physical Society primarily for submission to their own journals (the Physical Review series) but `revtex` can also be used for submissions to AIP and I believe a few other physics journals.

Comment: @DaiBowen Right, I misread something, will edit a bit. Thanks.